# Substitution for $\int \frac {dx} {ax^2 + bx + c}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm looking for the substitution that makes easier to solve integral containing quadratic polynomial in denominator (!) when such polynomial cannot be broken into parts (if it can, then it's possible to use partial fraction decomposition). Example:

$$\int \frac {dx} {5x^2 + x - 2}$$

Formulas suggested by wikipedia are hard to remember. So I hope there is some kind of substitution.

link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions#Integrands_of_the_form_xm_.2F_.28a_x2_.2B_b_x_.2B_c.29n

Comment: Although your example does factor into real linear factors, in cases where it doesn't, you should try to complete the square in the bottom.

Comment: @Sahar. the polynomial $5x^2+x-2$ has real roots $x_1$, $x_2$...why cannot split it in the product $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$?

Comment: @Avitus, I wrote coefficients for this example at random, so I'm not good RNG :)

Comment: For example $1/(x^2 + 2x + 10) = 1/[(x + 1)^2 + 3^2]$ and now substitute $u = x + 1$ and use arctangent formula.

Comment: @hot_queen, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reject use of complex numbers, and your denominator cannot be factored over the reals, then the method to use is: complete the square in the denominator, which will then suggest a trigonometric substitution.

Even if it CAN be factored, you could still complete the square and use a hyperbolic substitution...

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\frac1{ax^2+bx+c}=\frac{4a}{(2ax+b)^2+4ca-b^2}$$

Case $1:$ If $4ca-b^2=0,$ $$\int \frac{dx}{ax^2+bx+c}=4a\int\frac{dx}{(2ax+b)^2} $$ Put $y=2ax+b$

Case $2:$ If $4ca-b^2>0, 4ca-b^2=d^2$(say)

$$\int \frac{dx}{ax^2+bx+c}=4a\int\frac{dx}{(2ax+b)^2+d^2} $$

Put $2ax+b=d\tan\theta$ as $\tan^2\theta+1=\sec^2\theta$

Case $3:$  If $4ca-b^2<0, 4ca-b^2=-d^2$(say)

$$\int \frac{dx}{ax^2+bx+c}=4a\int\frac{dx}{(2ax+b)^2-d^2} $$

Put $2ax+b=d\sec\theta$  as $\sec^2\theta-1=\tan^2\theta$

Answer (score 1):

An idea:

$$5x^2+x-2=5\left(x-\frac{1-\sqrt{41}}{10}\right)\left(x-\frac{1+\sqrt{41}}{10}\right)$$

and now do partial fractions...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you can always find the complex roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ of a degree $2$ polynomial

$$ax^2+bx+c. $$

In order to evaluate the integral

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)} $$

try to use the residue theorem on the complex valued function $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-x-1)(z-x_2)}$
and an appropriate contour integral technique.The result would follow.

Comment: Trying to integrate *real* functions by means of complex non-real polynomials may well be strictly forbidden unless the student has already covered some basic complex analysis.

Comment: @DonAntonio I see; but then, if the roots of the polynomial are real, where is the problem?

Comment: @DonAntonio, agree with you, I doubt that I have enough knowledge of complex analysis to make sure that I won't make some mistake.

Comment: @Avitus, if the roots are real, then no problem exist, because I could use partial fraction decomposition. My question concerns the cases when there is no such decomposition is possible.

Comment: @Avitus, if the roots are real all is cool applying fractial partions. BTW, **also** if the roots are complex non-real this method works.

Comment: @Sahar, I'm afraid that you'll either have to memorize the formulae or else you will have to deduce each case separatedly each time...

Comment: @DonAntonio ok, but there is still something I cannot get: the OP talks about "when such polynomial cannot be broken into parts", which is a always possible procedure instead, considering complex roots. I thought his problem was about real/complex roots.

Comment: @Avitus, for what is worth: I'd go for complex roots and partial fractions, yet many instructors/lecturers won't agree with this approach.

Comment: @DonAntonio fine to me :)