# Evaluation of given expression of indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Integrate the following

$$\int \frac{dx}{(3x^2-4x+2)^{3/2}}$$

Can this be integrated in terms of elementary functions? Could someone please give me some hint to proceed in this problem? I tried it by taking $3x^2-4x+2=t^2$ but it didn't help.

Comment: See lab bhattacharjee's answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436768/substitution-for-int-frac-dx-ax2-bx-c and modify it slightly. Your integral would thus equate to $$\frac{3x-2}{2\sqrt{3x^2-4x+2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$3x^2-4x+2$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ with a negative discriminant. It follows that, through a suitable substitution, your problem boils down to computing
$$ \int \frac{dx}{(x^2+A^2)^{3/2}} =C+\frac{x}{A^2\sqrt{A^2+x^2}}$$
for some $A>0$. The last equality is easily proved by integration by parts.