# How to integrate $\frac{1}{x^2+x+2}$?

Tags: integration

I know the result is going to be in the inverse tangent form and i know you must complete the squares of the denominator to obtain this. I also know that you must use u-substitution method. However i am confused about the steps in between. Could anyone help?

step 1 : you complete the squares in the denominator (ans: $(x+0.5)^2 + 7/4$ )

step 2 : you find the derivative of the function $x^2+x+2 = 2x + 1$

step 3 : you use $u$-substitution

That's all I know, i don't know exactly what you should substitute in $u$ for.

The answer is : $$\frac{2\arctan(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt 7})}{\sqrt 7}  +C$$

Comment: I think it's best you actually show what you've tried. You mentioned completing the square as a first step, this is correct. But please show it. Edit your question with your working. It's best if you format your work in Mathjax, but someone can help you with that since you're new. Most important thing is you show that you've actually tried.

Comment: i've edited it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm typing out an answer

Comment: use lots of explanation please.

Comment: use ${(x+1/2)}^2+7/4=x^2=x+2$ and sub $u=x+1/2$

Comment: @furryhearts if you don't understand what they are saying, maybe you aren't ready to solve this integral.

Comment: @furryhearts After completing the square in the denominator, use ${(x+1/2)}$=$u$. Differentiating both the sides, you would get $du$=$dx$.

Comment: what the? why are u finding the derivative for the entire denominator?? put u = x+c and you find derivitive of u... you get du = dx. So its 1/(u^2+d)

Comment: where did you get x+0.5 from? @Essar

Comment: @furryhearts by completing the square... 2ab = 1, we know a = 1, so b must be 1/2

Comment: @furryhearts By completing the square in the denominator.

Comment: so once you get 1/(u^(2) + 7/4 ) du what do you do @Essar

Comment: how do you convert the 7/4 into 1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Substitution for $\int \frac {dx} {ax^2 + bx + c}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436768/substitution-for-int-frac-dx-ax2-bx-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you've shown some work, let me try to guide you through the rest.

First of all, completion of the square wasn't done correctly.

It should be $x^2 + x + 2 = x^2 + x + (\frac 12)^2 - \frac 14 + 2 = (x+\frac 12)^2 + \frac 74$

So now you're left with integrating $\frac 1{(x+\frac 12)^2 + \frac 74}$

I'm sure you've seen that the form $\frac 1{1+x^2}$ can be integrated to give $\arctan x + c$. The question is, can we make what we have look like this special form?

What are we lacking? Well, we have a fraction ($\frac 74$) where $1$ should be, for starters. Let's remedy that shall we?

$$\frac 1{(x+\frac 12)^2 + \frac 74} \\ = \frac {1}{\frac 74 (\frac 47(x+\frac 12)^2 + 1) } \\ = \frac 47 \cdot \frac {1}{1+(\frac 2{\sqrt 7}(x+\frac 12))^2}$$

Doesn't that look a lot like what you want?

If you now substitute $u = \frac 2{\sqrt 7}(x+\frac 12)$, what do you get? Can you finish?

Comment: yes, thanks for your answer. it's the only answer. and i edited my mistake. i think im doing too much maths at the moment, it makes me kind of prone to making stupid mistakes.

Comment: @furryhearts Yes, we all need a break from time to time. If my answer has helped you, please accept it.